# why react native webview injectedJavascript doesn't work on IOS?

Tags: react-native

I try to call a function from injectedJavascript of webview , in android it works fine , but on IOS it didn't work , could you help me on that , this is my webview :

```
<View style={container}>
        <WebView
          javaScriptEnabled={true}
          domStorageEnabled={true}
          injectedJavascript={this.jsCode.bind(this)}
          onNavigationStateChange={this.onNavigationStateChange}
          source={webapp}
          ref="WEBVIEW_REF"
          style={webView}
          decelerationRate="fast"
        />

      </View >
```

my function is :

```
jsCode() {
  let linn ='document.querySelector(".spl-bg2").style.color="blue";';
  return linn;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

**injectedJavaScript** is supposed to be a string that gets evaluated as javascript when the WebView loads so in your case it should work like this

```
let linn ='document.querySelector(".spl-bg2").style.color="blue";';
return(
  <View style={container}>
    <WebView
      javaScriptEnabled={true}
      domStorageEnabled={true}
      injectedJavaScript ={linn}
      onNavigationStateChange={this.onNavigationStateChange}
      source={webapp}
      ref="WEBVIEW_REF"
      style={webView}
      decelerationRate="fast"
    />
  </View>)
```

Update

This is a working example of the above, that runs on a website and changes the colour of the first paragraph it finds:

https://snack.expo.io/rJHiavAwX

Have a look at it and maybe you will find your issue. Note that the prop name is injectedJavaScript and not injectedJavascript as you have it in your example.

Comment: Thanks for ur help , but unfortunately it didn't work , even with adding a single quote to linn ..

Comment: I've updated my answer by adding a simple snack to demonstrate the functionality . If you're still having problems maybe set up a snack yourself and I will have a look. Good luck!

Comment: it wroks only if you put a direct link (ex : www.mysite.com) , in my case in source variable I am calling a local file (index.html) that contains links to visit

Comment: Hm...It works with local html files too... Which makes me think that there is something wrong with the html file you're importing, maybe a javascript error that prevents your code from running. Is there any way to share the imported html file or a part of it?